# Determining whether or not a font can render a Unicode character in Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, unicode, uifont

Is there a way to determine whether or not a font can render a particular Unicode character in Cocoa? Alternatively, is it possible to specify the default substitute character?

Comment: Are you working with `NSTextView`? If not, what do you want to use this information for?

Comment: No; I want to be able to highlight or replace unsupported characters in a UILabel on iPhone OS.

Comment: conmulligan: Then you mean Cocoa Touch, not Cocoa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CGFontGetGlyphWithGlyphName() for iOS older versions of iOS (2.0).  Apple doesn't seem to document the glyph names but I believe they correspond to this Adobe list:

http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/opentype/glyphlist.txt

For example, the glyph for é (U+00E9) is named "eacute" and the code to get the glyph would be:

```
CFStringRef name = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, "eacute", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
CGGlyph glyph = CGFontGetGlyphWithGlyphName(font, name);
```

Comment: A bit late, but glyph names are font specific and can be different from a font to another (some fonts might even not contain any glyph names at all).

Answer (score 3):

Check out `CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters` in the Core Text framework. If it returns zero for a given Unicode character's glyph index, then that character isn't supported in that font. The function returns false if any of the glyphs couldn't be found.

Comment: Core Text isn't really an option for me because it's only been introduced to iPhone OS with version 3.2 for the iPad.

Comment: In that case, you can use `CGFontGetGlyphWithGlyphName`, and pass in a string with just the character in question. I don't know what the rules are for composed characters, for example Helvetica on iPhone OS 3.1.3 has a glyph for e, but returns zero for é, ´, and combining acute accent.

Comment: This doesn't mean the glyph does not exist, it is more a reflection of the tables in the font file mapping characters to glyphs. The Apple Symbols font is a great example of this. It is probably the original font used precisely for providing lots of useful glyphs that are simply at a glyph index in the font file, but not necessarily mapped to a character. This is where familiarity with FontBook and the glyphs in a specific font by font index are helpful. but for iOS you may need to find or create an app that helps you review the glyphs at indexes in a specific font.

Comment: @Tony é may not be a single character in terms of the the font you're looking at. It may be ultimately composed by ´ and e

Answer (score 1):

Since it is on iOS, you might need to build or find an app that does this.
Ultimately, if the info is present for any individual glyph it is in the tables in the font file itself and that is pretty low level C work.

Much easier to build a tool that inspects the font and shows the glyph and glyph index (CGGlyph or NSGlyph value) then use the glyph index.